# find a length of a vector in polar coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

Even after reading several answers to similar question I am having ([A question about vector representation in polar coordinates.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3951951), [how to compute length in polar coordinates?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1444090)), I feel still confused. Lets say, we have the following [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifOLy.png) of finding the length of a vector $|\textbf{a}|$ in polar coordinates. If I define $a_{\theta} = a \sin(\theta)$ and $a_{r} = a \cos(\theta)$,
$$|\textbf{a}|^2 =a_{\theta} ^2 + a_{r}^2  $$

Then I guess, it is not the formula in polar coord. but in local cartesian coord. defined at the point A. Following the answers: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4325357 or  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1444388, I guess it is rather expressed in polar coord. as
$$|\textbf{a}|^2 = r^2 a_{\theta} ^2 + a_{r}^2 $$
Then I don't know what is meant by $a_{\theta}$ or how to compute it. Please elaborate on that!

Comment: Vector in cartesian coordinates can be described by two numbers $a_x$, $a_y$ which are constant at translation of vector. Vector in polar coordinates can also be described by two invariant to translation numbers: length $|\vec{a}|$ and angle $\theta$ to the polar axis. If you need to describe vector by some non-invariant to translation numbers, then you can use for example polar coordinates of begin and end of the vector: $r_1$, $\theta_1$, $r_2$, $\theta_2$. Then length of the vector can be found using cosine rule: $|\vec{a}|=\sqrt{r_1^2+r_2^2-2r_1 r_2\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)}$.

Comment: Oh, I see the point: since the space is flat, I can translate my vector along the radius vector until its tail matches with the origin and then I am fine. But I am wondering what he meant by $a_r$ and $a_{\theta}$ when he wrote $$\begin{bmatrix}a_x\\a_y\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}\cos \theta &-r\sin \theta \\\sin \theta &r\cos \theta \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}a_r\\a_{\theta} \end{bmatrix}$$ (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4325357) with which if I compute the length it becomes $|\vec{a}| = a_r^2 + r^2 a_\theta^2 $

Answer (score 1):

I was reading Mary L. Boas (Chapter 10, section 10)and it looks like my confusion originates from ignoring the fact that the contravariant and physical components of a vector are different in general. If we consider the line element in polar coordinates then the physical components are *$dr$* and *r $d\theta$* seen by,

$$d\textbf{s} =  dr \textbf{e}_r + r d{\theta} \textbf{e}_{\theta}$$

But if I calculate the components using the definition of contravariant vectors ($ds^{\hat{i}} = \frac{\partial x^\hat{i}}{\partial x^i} ds^{i}$), I get
$$ds^{\hat{1}}= \cos(\theta) dx + \sin(\theta) dy = dr$$
$$ds^{\hat{2}} = -\sin(\theta) dx + \cos(\theta) dy = d\theta$$

Therefore in my question $a_{\theta}$ stands for the contravariant component of $\textbf{a}$ not the physical component with which I would find the length. We have to multiply the covariant component with the scale factor to find the physical component. Taking this into account

$$|\textbf{a}|^2 = (a^{phys.}_{\theta})^2 + (a_r)^2$$

Now, it is just a Pythagorean theorem in a locally constructed cartesian coordinate.